# R, remove rows with empty strings from data.frame across all columns

Tags: string, r, dataframe

I would like to remove all rows from the data frame where any of the available columns has a string of zero length. I tried making use of the **complete cases** function but it doesn't work as, presumably some of the strings have empty white spaces. Consequently, I would like to search all columns of the data.frame and remove all rows that have an empty string in one of the available columns. My data frame is defined as **ladata**.

```
# Remove incomplete cases
ladta <- ladta[complete.cases(ladta),]
```

Comment: The code doesn't work, the error is `Error: unexpected ']' in "ladta <- ladta[-apply(ladta, 1, function(x) any(x==""),]"`. With respect to the data is a simple table with 3 columns 230K rows and blank spaces here and there.

Comment: Cases are complete if there are no `NA` values.  You might change how you're reading the data so that you get `NA` instead of empty string values.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
 ladta <- ladta[!apply(ladta, 1, function(x) any(x=="")),]
```

Here, `apply` gives each row to `any`, which checks if the expression `x==""` (which is itself a vector) is true for any of the elements and if so, it returns `TRUE`. The whole `apply` expression thus returns a vector of `TRUE/FALSE` statements, which are negated with `!`. This can then be used to subset your data.

Comment: Great general answer.  Works for eliminating rows containing only empty strings too by replacing any() with all()